# ASP.NET MVC reuseable controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a question about reuseable controls in ASP.NET MVC 3.

In our application we have a lot of tales on different pages. The tables have all the same logic, so we put a table in its own controller and view.
The data source and certain individual properties are submitted to the tablecontroller as parameter. The controller store the parameters in the tempdata to save them for self request by the tableview.

The table raises an AJAX request when sorting or paging, so that only parts of the table are updated. The request goes directly to the tablecontroller. The tablecontroller requires the parameters that we stored in the tempdata. So the table can call itself, without losing the data source and the properties.

My question is whether there is a better solution?

The current approach is not so nice, because the TempData are occupied with data to the end of the session. The pages and tables are linked and the user can switch between there. So its difficult to determine when certain parameters are no longer needed.

What is the best solution to build your own parameterized controls in MVC?

Answer (score 0):

The right build your own parameterized controls in MVC in using [Declarative Helpers](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/03/23/comparing-mvc-3-helpers-using-extension-methods-and-declarative-razor-helper.aspx). 
However, this solution may be not flexible enough for asynchronous client-server interaction. For such interactive controls may be the best implementation is [javascript template engine](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender).